# Is $e^z\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^3}{3^k}z^k$ analytic inside $|z|=3$?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Am I correct that the following function is analytic at least inside $|z|=3$? (I used the ratio test.) The solutions manual says that the function is analytic on and inside |z|=1, so I wonder if I'm having a conceptual misunderstanding. $$e^z\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^3}{3^k}z^k$$

Also, is it possible to see/guess from a glance the radius of convergence of this particular function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $e^z$ is an entire function, which never vanishes. So analyticity of your function is equivalent to the analyticity of the power series $\sum k^3/3^kz^k.$
This series converges for $|z|<3,$ as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks. I read though that the convergence radius of the product of two limit functions could possibly be bigger than the smaller of the two component radii.

Comment: Right you are. That's why I mentioned that $e^z$ never vanishes. Otherwise, take $f(z)=z-1$ and the power series of $g(z)=\frac{e^z}{1-z}$ for $|z|<1.$

Comment: I mean, in your main answer, you argued that it is equivalent, but the reasoning is wrong, isnt it (although the conclusion is correct in this case)? Just checking my understanding.

Comment: I said that it is equivalent after I mentioned that $e^z$ is entire and never vanishes. In this case, it is indeed equivalent

Comment: ? How does that alone guarantee that the resultant radius cannot be bigger than the smaller component radius?